# How to set stroke align in Adobe Illustrator with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, alignment, adobe, stroke

Adobe Illustrator provide JavaScript lib to build batch script.

```
var doc = activeDocument;
var rect = doc.pathItems.rectangle(700, 80, 400, 70);
rect.stroked = true;    // open stroke
rect.strokeWidth = 3;
var newRGBColor = new RGBColor();
newRGBColor.red = 200;
newRGBColor.green = 120;
newRGBColor.blue = 240;
rect.strokeColor = newRGBColor;
// and we also can set StrokeJoin and StrokeCap
```

But I can't find how to set stroke align...

Comment: Consider adding some more details to your question.

Answer (score -1):

Late, but here you go:

```
rect.strokeCap = StrokeCap.BUTTENDCAP;//ROUNDENDCAP, PROJECTINGENDCAP
rect.strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.ROUNDENDJOIN;//BEVELENDJOIN, MITERENDJOIN
```